# Photo gallery with Featured Images

Tags: post-thumbnails, gallery

First, I need to ask if it's possible to create a photo gallery only with the featured images of the latest 6 posts? I assume it is possible but just want to make sure.

I don't have much experience working directly with the wordpress gallery so could someone point me in the right direction for accomplishing this? Any plugin with similar functionally or tutorial will do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$query = new WP_Query(array('posts_per_page' => 6, 'meta_key' => '_thumbnail_id'));
while($query->have_posts()) :
    $query->the_post();
    the_post_thumbnail();
endwhile;
```

This code gets 6 latest posts which have featured image available & show those 6 images on the page. It will skip those posts where there is no featured image set even if they are newer.

This will probably get you started. You should read the codex pages for `WP_Query` & `the_post_thumbnail`

Comment: Thanks for helping! Will test the code and read the codex.

Answer (score 3):

As I just ran into that problem yesterday, here's the solution: You'll have to set `numberposts` as well as `posts_per_page` to cover every edge case scenario.

I also included the possibility to query for attached files as well as a check if there're any attachments.

```
$wpse69856_query = new WP_Query( array(
     'posts_per_page' => 6
    ,'numberposts'    => 6
    ,'meta_key'       => '_thumbnail_id'
    // For non-featured images
    ,'meta_key'       => '_wp_attached_file'
) );
if ( $wpse69856_query->have_posts() )
{
    while( $wpse69856_query->have_posts() )
    {
        $wpse69856_query->the_post();
        the_post_thumbnail();
    }
}
```

**Note:** This is just an addition to @Mridul Aggarwal answer to make it more complete. In the case this works for you, please mark his answer as solution. Thanks.

Comment: thanks for your input. One small question though: I don't understand the use of `numberposts`, could you please explain a bit?

Comment: @MridulAggarwal To be honest, I don't remember it - currently wresting with a new server and dozens of other things. As far as I can remember, the one takes only the current page in account (affected by pagination) and the other one takes all posts. But I can also be wrong on this issue. I just dumped both queries on `'posts_clauses'` to get the pieces and `'posts_request'` to get the final query string and then inspected the result. There was also some other plugin of mine interfering, so as I said: I can also be wrong in this case :)

Comment: Thanks to both of you for helping. Mridul code works, now I just need to customize it a bit and probably include it in a widget.